# access Lync / Skype for Business conversation in C#

Tags: c#, skype, skype-for-business, lync

I'm facing a use case, where it shall be possible to take over a Lync/Skype for Business Conversation into my Software. The help desk user was contacted by a customer via Skype for Business and now needs to create a ticket from that conversation. Only the chat-conversation is needed, no voip conversations or so.

I could not find any documentation about how to start any Actions out of a Skype for Business conversation window.

I'm sure, somebody solved that before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that:

- "Skype for Business" is basically a rebranded Lync, so Shane's advice about the "Lync Client SDK" is correct.
- "Skype" != "Skype for Business". It's like java and javascript, totally different, just similar names for branding.
- Persistent Chat means "chat rooms that remain". Skype for Business has regular IM chat and its much less used "Persistent Chat".
- tel.red can do this for you if you pay them.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is to use the [Lync Client SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj933180.aspx) specifically the parts dealing with [Persistent Chat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj933070.aspx), there are [samples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj933148.aspx) you can play with.

If you don't want to integrate into the Lync Client itself, you can go down the [UCMA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn454984%28v=office.16%29.aspx) route and create a "[bot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn454823%28v=office.16%29.aspx)" that can take part in chat conversations.

Comment: Does the Client SDK contain any of the persistent chat libraries or is it necessary to download the Persistent Chat SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Using Skype's own API is probably the best way.

http://www.skype.com/en/developer/

Comment: Does Skype API also work with Skype for Business from scratch?

Comment: Yes, it should.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt650889(v=office.16).aspx

Comment: Is it possible to place a Skype to Skype call from C# or VB.net (desktop stand alone app) ... I managed to open Skype for business and open chat window but cannot auto-call someone on my list... Any ideas?

Comment: I will add an another link for skype for business API : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/appsdk/apioverview

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to get the lync sdk controls to work when Skype for business/lync is running using app-v.  it works fine when the program is "installed" though.

when running Skype for business/lync in app-v, the error is basically lync client not found, even though it is obviously running.